# MongoDB , selects not getting the latest updates

Tags: mongodb, consistency

We have a small Mongo DB 3.2v (2 nodes)for bookkeeping where keep information about different files to be loaded into a different MPP DB.

Mongo just stores filename and status of the file. Python Loading process changes the status for each file picked (ready->waiting ->working) and loads into another MPP DB.

There are multiple processes which can run in parallel and change the status of a file.The problem is that whenever a process p1 updates a file status (uses find_one_and_update), another parallel process p2 running around the same time is not getting the updated status of the file and picks the same file as p1.

**Why do I observe this consistency problem on Mongo?**

The read does is not reflecting the latest write. This is causing issues where we end up loading same file twice.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no caching systems in place in your middle-tier, then it may be a case of changing the relevant [read](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/read-concern/) and [write](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/write-concern/) concerns for your queries and operations.

As you have multiple nodes, you may be returning queries that have not had updates acknowledged between all members.

The query default is [local](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/read-concern-local/):

*A query with read concern "local" returns data from the instance with no guarantee that the data has been written to a majority of the replica set members (i.e. may be rolled back).*

You may need to change to [linearizable](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/read-concern-linearizable/) or `majority`

*The query returns data that reflects all successful majority-acknowledged writes that completed prior to the start of the read operation. The query may wait for concurrently executing writes to propagate to a majority of replica set members before returning results.*

```
db.restaurants.find( { _id: 5 } ).readConcern("linearizable").maxTimeMS(10000)
```

Comment: Samuel - `spec ={ "update":{"$set": {"Data.statusCode": Constants.Work}}}
  myQuery = {"Data.statusCode":Constants.Wait}
  fd = self.repository.collection( testcollectionname() ).find_one_and_update(myQuery,return_document=ReturnDocument.AFTER,**spec )`
How do I change this query to have read concern " linearizable "using pymongo

Comment: Application always connects to primary and secondary has been prevented from becoming primary

Comment: I have not used Pymongo but seems you set the values on the [collection](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection) not the query. check the docs: [collection](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection), [write concern](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/write_concern.html) and [read concern](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/read_concern.html)